# Log Analysis and data aggregation

Tags: logging, lucene, data-analysis

I'm totally new to data analysis and I need some advice to start a new project.
I have a number of log files from different peripherals which are part of an automatic payment machine. Log files are produced day-by-day and each one is between 10k and 100k lines long. Moreover, log files have more or less the same structure (Timestamp, Category, ProcID, ThreadID, Method, Message).
What I need to do is:

1. apply some queries to each file to extract information about each peripheral
2. aggregate information from log of different peripherals to reconstruct the transaction flow

Which are the best techniques/frameworks for doing this task? 
I've just started using Apache Lucene for log parsing, but I will appreciate any kind of advice.
At the moment I have no constraint about programming language, but it should preferably be Java, C# or Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a database approach.  You will need to be familiar with SQL.

1. Use a python script to extract info needed into a format that can be imported to databases.
2. Export it to a database (such as PostgreSQL, or Apache SPARK) with each peripheral being a table.  Of course, if the # of peripherals you need to match is a lot, you need to optimize the tables a bit by putting one-to-one matched peripheral entries into one table.
3. Then perform JOIN operation to match corresponding peripherals.
4. Compose / reconstruct the transaction flow based on the matching peripheral info.

The advantage of this approach is easily scalable.  Also, most data science tools support databases.  So you can use various tools to inspect / visualize your data.  It also sets you up for more complicated operations that you may need.